# Using function from another namespace C++

Tags: c++

I want to create aliases for a few of the Range-V3 functions/functors into my own namespace. For the functors like begin, end, it's just doing `auto constexpr begin = ::ranges::begin`. However, for a function like copy, I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tried `using ::ranges::copy();` and `using ::ranges::copy;` but neither work.

Any help would be much appreciated! A small example of what I'm doing:

```
namespace example::ranges
{
   auto constexpr begin = ::ranges::begin;
   auto constexpr end = ::ranges::end;
   auto constexpr size = ::ranges::size;
   using ::ranges::copy(); // Doesn't work
}
```

Comment: What is `::ranges::copy`? A function, a class, a typedef,... ? Maybe already a `using`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you only want to create "a few" aliases? Otherwise it would be as simple as `namespace example { namespace ranges = ::ranges; }`.

Comment: `using ::ranges::copy;` didn't work? Really?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no straightforward way to create aliases for functions in C++ (yet). Your best bet is creating a perfectly-forwarding wrapper:

```
namespace example::ranges
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    auto begin(Ts&&... xs)                   
        noexcept(noexcept(::ranges::begin(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...))) 
              -> decltype(::ranges::begin(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...)) {
                   return ::ranges::begin(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    }
}
```

This will behavely as closely as possible to the original function, retaining its `noexcept`-ness, SFINAE-friendliness, and overloaded behavior. The triplication can be simplified with a macro.

Comment: Ahhh I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. What do you mean by "yet"? Is it planned for C++20?

Comment: @brrrlinguist: [this](http://wg21.link/p0945) was discussed in Rapperswil, but there was no consensus

Comment: I think the `noexcept` specifier should appear before the trailing return type. Can you please fix it?